# Good practice for parent model field udpate with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 3 models having this relationship:

Course ==> [Chapter] ==> Quiz

i.e., I have a Course model containing an array of `ObjectId` referencing Chapter documents, and my Chapter model contains an `ObjectId` referencing a Quiz document.

In my Course schema definition, I have a `lastUpdated` field which stores the date at which the last modification of the course was performed.

Schemas definition are given below:

Course schema:

```
let courseScheme = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        nbChapters: { type: Number, default: 0 },
        chapters: { type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId], default: [], ref: 'Chapter' },
        lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }, // I want this field to be updated if I create/update/delete a reference or a transitive reference of this document
    }
);
```

Chapter schema:

```
let chapterScheme = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        chapterName: {type: String, required: true},
        chapterIndex: {type: Number, required: true}, // used to sort chapters on client side (for ex: in navigation menu)
        course: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Course' },
        quizzId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Quiz'},
        // some more fields
    }
);
```

Quiz schema:

```
let quizScheme = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        questions: [
            {
                questionIndex: {type: Number, required: true}, // used to sort questions on client side
                type: {type: String, required: true, enum: ['MultiSelect', 'Select', 'Input']},
                question: {type: String, required: true}
                // some more fields
            },
        ]
    }
);
```

I'd like to know if there's any good practice to update the `lastUpdated` field in my course document, if I make a modification to any of its child (direct/indirect). For example, if I add a new quiz reference to a chapter of a given course, how would one update the `lastUpdated` field of the corresponding course?

I've thought of doing the following:

- Using hooks to update this field everytime I update/save a new child document of a course
- Directly query the parent course and update its field whenever required

PS: I'm not asking for code as an answer, just some hints about what are common good practices for this kind of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you have 2 possible approaches:

1. **Handle when updating the DB**
   Update the `lastUpdated` field upon changes to linked schemas. You have a few approaches for this (some you have mentioned)

   - Use 2 operations (2 requests/2 operations): update `chapters` than update `courses`
   - Use a hook (also 2 requests/2 operations)
   - Use a batch/[bulk](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.execute/#Bulk.execute) update (1 request, 2 operations): this would be most efficient since you only send one outgoing request to MongoDB. However, still 2 operations occur on the MongoDB server.
2. **Handle when querying the DB**
   Don't update the `lastUpdated` field on the `courses` collection if a change was made to another collection. Instead, keep a `lastUpdated` field on all relevant collections, and choose the most recent date when querying. 

   **Example**
    When you are querying your data, use a `$lookup` aggregation on two collections, `chapters` and `courses`. On the result, chose the most recent `lastUpdated` date - either from `courses` or from `chapters`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed this helps. I didn't even know about bulk operations, and will take a look to choose between all approaches, according to my needs and the context of my application/env etc... Thank you!